# How to add a second Sql Server instance on an OVH dedicated server?

Tags: ovh

Some context:

- we have purchased an OVH dedicated server, and simultaneously purchased software licences : Windows Server 2022 and Sql Server 2019 Web Edition.
- operating system and purchased software are automatically installed by the provider
- after less than one hour, we can begin to play with our first MSSQLSERVER instance, which is the default name of the first Sql Server instance.

Fine until here.

We would like host in this dedicated server several different roles (say, for example, production backup, development, preproduction, etc.). According to our policies, the databases used by each of these roles should be segregated in their own SqlServer instance.

Issues begin there!

1. SQL Server Installation Center requires an installation media, that I do not have.
2. I have downloaded a SQL Server free evaluation iso, mounted it and run the setup from there. No luck either as the SQL Server Installation Center now requires a product key, that I do not have.
3. Because the Sql Server Web Edition is only available through hosting companies, it is not directly downloadable on MS sites (at least, I didn't found it)
4. The OVH unattended installation process leaves a "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Setup Bootstrap" folder, but it is not suitable as an installation media (because doesn't have any .msi file).
5. I have opened a ticket to the OVH support center, without any result for the moment.

So, I need some help, please ;)

- is there another way to define a second SqlServer instance ?
- does anyone has already succeeded to define a second SqlServer instance in this context ?

Thanks in advance.
Regards